# Getting errors in NuiApi.h when compiling project with kinect sdk

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, console, kinect

For the purposes of testing ,I have tried building a win32 console project (empty project) so as to compile make sure that the kinect sdk would work.

On building i got hundreds of errors in NuiApi.h

All I have done was to include NuiApi.h in my source code i did nothing else.

here is the project

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4740547/ConsoleApplication1.zip

Try to building it and you will see all the errors pop up. I would be really grateful if anyone can tell me where im going wrong.

Comment: Figured out what the problem was - All I needed to do was Add #include <windows.h> and more importantly uncheck the precompiled libraries option when creating the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what the problem was - All I needed to do was Add #include  and more importantly uncheck the precompiled libraries option when creating the project.